# Trouble writing and formatting data to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am having trouble with the formatting of my csv file. I want to send the output from code (either 1 (or 255) and 0) to a csv file so that I can analyze these values later in Excel. This is the code I have so far, but I would like the output in the cvs file to be one very long column of data values.

I am also having issues with the `writer_object.writerow(DataList)` line because when it is indented as such, no data values appear in the csv file. Any ideas on what to do to the code so that I can get one long list of data values that would appear as one big column of values in a csv file (similar to how there can be one long column of data values in an Excel sheet)?

```
list_of_source = [
["/media/pi/T3 1TB 2Ch xFer/Ramzy Masked /Arena1"],
["/media/pi/T3 1TB 2Ch xFer/Ramzy Masked /Arena2"],
["/media/pi/T3 1TB 2Ch xFer/Ramzy Masked /Arena3"],
["/media/pi/T3 1TB 2Ch xFer/Ramzy Masked /Arena4"],
["/media/pi/T3 1TB 2Ch xFer/Ramzy Masked /Arena5"]]

DataList = []
with open('behavioraldata.csv', 'w') as f_object:
    writer_object = csv.writer(f_object)
    for row in list_of_source:
        directory = row[0]
        filelist = os.listdir(directory)
        filelists = sorted(filelist,key=lambda x:int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]))
    
        for x, y in zip(filelists[:-1], filelists[1:]):
            imgX = cv2.imread(os.path.join(directory, x)).astype(np.float_)
            imgY = cv2.imread(os.path.join(directory, y)).astype(np.float_)
            imgZ = cv2.absdiff(imgX, imgY)
    
            thresh = cv2.threshold(imgZ, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
            np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
            data = asarray(thresh)
    
            Maximum = np.max(data)
            if Maximum == 255:
                print(1)
            if Maximum == 0:
                print(0)
            DataList.append(Maximum)
            
        writer_object.writerow(DataList)
        print("Done")
```

Comment: How is the output CSV from your code different from the desired result?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. What is `list_of_source`? Can you create an example that doesn't use filepaths? What debugging steps have you done on your own?

Comment: `writerow()` is for writing a single row passed as a sequence of values each of which is a separate column value. If you want to write a CSV file with one column, use `writerows()` and pass it a sequence of sequences, where the nested sequences are each only one element long.

Comment: @bicarlsen the way it comes out now is as a long row rather than a long column of values.

Comment: @OneCricketeer list_of_sources is a list of lists that contain the paths to a specific folder that contains images. The goal of the code above is to do image subtraction of consecutive images to determine if there is a difference between consecutive images. I will upload a piece of the list_of_resources right now.

Comment: There's nothing particularly unique about "subtracting images" for the `DataList` to be non-empty. Specifically, if the `zip()` creates an empty list, the loop doesn't run, so there will be nothing in the output file

Answer (score 0):

The reason your data is coming out as a rows isntead of columns is becaue you are creating a list `DataList`, then using the `csv.writer.writerow` method, which writes a list as a row.

It seems you have two options here.

1. If you just want a flat CSV file you can just write each piece of data to the "plainly"

```py
with open( 'test.csv', 'w' ) as f_object:
    for i in range( 3 ):
        for j in range( 3 ):
            f_object.write( f'{j*i}\n' )
```

2. Use the `csv` module, but call `writer.writerow` in the inner loop instead of creating a list and then writing the data.

```py
import csv


with open( 'test.csv', 'w' ) as f_object:
    writer = csv.writer( f_object )
    for i in range( 3 ):
        for j in range( 3 ):
            writer.writerow( [ i*j ] )
```